# "TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable" with several variables

Tags: python-3.x

I have several variables, playerHealth and ogreHealth.

I use a defined function to change them, according to some other things.

Useful code:

```
def attack(enemyHealth, playerHealth):
```

```
while saveKeyp or place == 'b':
    [ogreHealth, playerHealth] = attack(ogreHealth, playerHealth)
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: if `attack` returns an integer you cannot unpack in into multiple values.

Comment: What does `attack` do?  What does it return?

Comment: The `[ ... ]` around your variable list are not necessary, although they don't change the meaning (much). `x, y = foo(stuff)` is sufficient as long as `foo()` returns 2 (or more) values in a tuple.

Comment: A short snidbit of attack is https://hastebin.com/teqayarufa.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going with the guess from Jean-François Fabre (since you haven't shown the code for `attack`), it looks like the `attack` function is returning only one value:

```
# guessing attack's implementation
    return a_health_value
```

Because only one health value is being returned Python is complaining that it cannot iterate through that object to get two health values.  What you should do instead:

```
    return calculated_enemy_health, calculated_player_health
```

By returning a tuple of two values, Python will be able to iterate through the tuple and assign those values to `ogreHealth` and `playerHealth`.

Comment: This did work, in my code I was returning the two values as separate things, so that's why it wasn't working! Thanks!